# "I would not know", "How should I know?" Are they interchangeable?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could we say that, "I wouldn't know" and "How should I know?" have the same  meaning?
Can we use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 3):

They are similar in meaning, but vastly different in politeness.

From most apologetic to most insulting...

> I'm sorry, I don't know
>
> I wouldn't know
>
> How should I know?

The first would be acceptable in polite society, the last might be worthy of a punch in the face.